# How do I do a fresh install of Google App Engine?

Tags: macos, google-app-engine

I've been using GAE for months now, but very recently I've had difficulty getting the latest release (1.3.4) to work for me. I'd like to remove GAE and start from scratch and reinstall it. However, it appears that deleting the googleappenginelauncher.app is not enough to completely remove it, because when I install the launcher again I see that it remembers the applications it was running previously (so at a minimum, there are some config files out there that I'm not removing properly). I'm new to Macs, so if there are other things I need to do besides deleting the .app, please let me know. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config files are typically stored in ~/Library/Application Support, but the config files there shouldn't affect the behaviour of the launcher in ways that prevent it from working. Perhaps if you tell us what problems you're having, we can suggest a solution?

Comment: Specifically, when I run the launcher, I see in the "About GoogleAppEngineLauncher" that I'm running version 1.3.4.794. However, when I click "SDK Console" from the launcher and click on the "Task Queues" area, I still see "Tasks will not run automatically. Select a queue to run tasks manually.", which makes me think that the code for the SDK was not updated properly, since I still have to run tasks manually.

Comment: Nick, I'm marking this answer as correct because I was able to find the config file you mentioned, although unfortunately the reinstall didn't fix the core issue I was having, so I've asked a new question focused on the issue I mention in my previous comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949376/app-engine-sdk-console-not-fully-updated-on-osx-for-gae-release-1-3-4